# Regarding varying the coefficients of constraints in the pre-extended Hamiltonian in Dirac method

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

consider the following variational principle:

[image]

when we vary $p$ and $q$ independently to find the equations of motion, why aren't we explicitly varying the Coeff $u$ which are clearly functions of $p$ and $q$? the authors also either didn't vary $u$ and got the EOM (or) varied $u$ but neglected it since $\phi_m$ are ultimately zero on shell:

[image]

so, my question is which one of the above they did and why?

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; subsection 1.1.4: eqs. (1.12) + (1.13).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that at this point in Ref. 1 $u^m$ are new independent variables; not functions of $q$ and $p$. Equivalently, $u^m$ are [Lagrange undetermined multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

It is possibly helpful to mention that a field redefinition $u^m\to u^m +U^m(q,p)$ is allowed.

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; subsection 1.1.4: eqs. (1.12) + (1.13).
2. P.A.M. Dirac, *Lectures on QM,* 1964; eqs. (1-7)+ (1-8).